# Samsung Series 5 with bad output image quality

Tags: 12.10, samsung

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04.02 64bit on my Samsung however I noticed bad HDMI / VGA quality on a Full HD TV.

```
    VGAs: Intel HD4000 and Nvidia GT 630M 2GB
    Resolutions:
    Laptop: 1366x768
    Tv: 1920x1080
```

I'm currently using only the Intel VGA, the Nvidia drivers are not loaded.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Maggotbrain, I'm new to askubuntu and I liked a lot this site! I'm gonna split my question.